# MySQL update using NOW() performing very slow

Tags: mysql, sql

For the last few days, I have observed a simple update query performing very badly. The update time ranges from 2.5 seconds to 15 seconds. The query has been working within performance limits (*<1 sec*) for the last year and a half but has suddenly started showing degraded performance over the last two days. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

```
update user.auth_token 
set last_access_time = NOW() 
where token = '488f4f040090f1cb749e09a514d3dd3d';
```

The table contains only 9 rows and has the following definition.

```
CREATE TABLE `auth_token` (
    `user_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `token` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_access_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `creation_time` datetime NOT NULL,
    `token_type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `token_UNIQUE` (`token`),
    KEY `fk_user_name_idx` (`user_name`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_user_name` FOREIGN KEY (`user_name`) 
        REFERENCES `user` (`name`) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

MySQL version is `5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log`

**Update**
The explain output is as follows:

```
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'auth_token', 'const', 'token_UNIQUE', 'token_UNIQUE', '138', 'const', '1', ''
```

Comment: Any more data would be greatly appreciated. EXPLAIN plan for example. Any additional indexes? Statistics for the table?

Comment: Please add the execution plan of the query, `NOW`  shouldn't slow your query.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table?  It seems highly unlikely that `now()` is affecting the timings on such a small table.

Comment: @SandeepDeb Dont post it as comment, just edit your question with the adiitional info

Comment: Your query looks ok either you have a trigger for that table or your db is busy with other requests or your hdd are slow. Also there is a delete cascade, so you have to check for triggers there too.

Comment: Thanks for the queries. The table has no triggers, no foreign key references point to the token field and the table has only 9 rows :( For the time being I have taken out this query from the critical path and the system doesn't slow down at all.. no other query seems to be showing similar performance degradations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like the unique key on token might as well be a primary key.

Not having an explicit PK will cause innoDB to add a hidden PK to that table and have all secondary indexes reference that hidden PK.

Whenever that PK is created it takes a global lock in the server making unrelated queries effect each other in ways that are very hard to find out.

I would also try to remove the foreign key and execute the same query again, just to make sure that isn't getting in the way of anything.

```
alter table auth_token add primary key (token),
                       drop key token_unique,
                       drop foreign key fk_user_name;
```

Comment: Thank you #Andreas. I have made the changes (except the foreign key) and have got back the query in the critical path. I am now keeping the system under observation. It has been 10 minutes and I still don't see the offending query in the mysql-slow log. Give me till tomorrow to revert back if this solved the problem. I am still very puzzled how this cropped up out of the blue when the system was working for the last many months. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be working. Your explanation of a global lock in the server matches the observational behavior. I had also observed that the load average of the system was relatively high when this query was misbehaving (around 2.x), but came down to the expected 0.0x once I dropped the unique constraint and made it a PK instead. Many thanks for your suggestion!